# Name that Entity (5) - Don't be fooled by my grandiloquence

Tags: riddle, word

Don't be fooled by my grandiloquence
look past the words to find my substance

Past my skin if you shall pry
my prominent brother will make you cry

I am almost shallow but don't confuse
Utilise my extract to infuse

Your boiling, frying if allotment you find
Contain your grief, compose and grind

Comment: If someone can post an answer which fits every clue, and is different to one I have announced as the correct answer. I'll comply and delete this as it would be in the majorities opinion be off topic. That should be the standard of the riddles on this site no?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Shallot.

Explanation:

*Dont be fooled by my grandiloquence 

 look past the words to find my substance*

> Just distraction? "Look past the words" meaning the words in these two lines?

*Past my skin if you shall pry 

 my prominent brother will make you cry*

> "My prominent brother" is the onion. You cry if you open a shallot or onion.

*I am almost shallow but dont confuse 

 Utilise my extract to infuse*

> "Almost shallow" is a nice bit of wordplay: 'shallot' and 'shallow' are only one letter different. Not sure about the next line: can shallot extract be used for something?

*Your boiling, frying if allotment you find 

 Contain your grief, compose and grind*

> You can boil or fry shallots, or grow them in an allotment (which is another bit of wordplay: 'shallot' and 'allotment'). If you can stop crying after peeling a shallot, you can then grind it.

Comment: not even 2 minutes give that man a sandwich!

Comment: @Oblongamous - Not an onion sandwich, please :-) I was almost sure just from the 3rd and 4th lines, and the 5th clinched it. (I'll delete this comment if you think it gives away too much.)

Comment: fair enough no its ok im trying to move away from metaphoric riddles and use wordplay also. Here it seems you had eyes of a hawk :D

Comment: @Oblongamous - Great, I'll look out for your next riddle - I love wordplay! It really annoys my friends sometimes :-p